# Json Decode not taking action on curl

Tags: php, json

Im trying to decode a json that its comming from a curl call, this is what im doing:

```
$url = "https://api.web.net/login/auth.php";

$curl_post_data = array(
    'username' => 'myuser',
    'password' => '12345'
);

//url-ify the data for the POST
$fields_string = http_build_query($curl_post_data);

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($result);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($obj);
echo "</pre>";


//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

This is now what im getting from the curl call with json decode and i cant do an array list or print

```
{"ts":"523453245","_id":"5435","result":{"status":"success","aditional_data":[],"entitydata":"token here"}}
```

What im doing wrong?, i cant access to the entitydata to set my token.

Comment: You're missing `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` curl option I reckon.

Comment: This works!, thank you!, this allows me to use an object.

Comment: json_decode returns an object. To see the keys for example do a typecast like this: `print_r(array_keys((array)$obj));`

Comment: How are you trying to access the `entitydata` property?

Comment: I got it to work by using this `echo $obj->result->entitydata;`